# Redrawing the tooltip inside of the tooltip positioner callback

Tags: highcharts

I'm using the I'm currently using the tooltip formatter function to control the look of the tooltip, including adding some custom css to create an arrow on the side of the tooltip box facing the mouse. I am also using the positioner callback to not only determine the placement of the tooltip, but when it changes from one side of the mouse to the other I'm updating the formatter callback to switch the side of the tooltip the arrow lies on (see code below). Everything works fine, except for the very first point which causes the tooltip to switch sides of the mouse. Its clear that a tooltip's "formatter" function is called before the tooltips "positioner" function ( for reasons that are probably obvious ). However, it prevents me from correctly drawing the tooltip when it changes sides. What I really need to be able to do in the positioner callback is to update the formatter function, and then redraw the tooltip. Is that possible?

```
positioner: function (boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
    // Set up the variables
    var chart = this.chart;
    var plotLeft = chart.plotLeft;
    var plotTop = chart.plotTop;
    var plotWidth = chart.plotWidth;
    var plotHeight = chart.plotHeight;
    var distance = 40;
    var pointX = point.plotX;
    var pointY = point.plotY;

    // Determine if we need to flip the tooltip from following on the left to
    // following on the right
    if ((pointX - boxWidth - distance) < plotLeft) {
        x = pointX + distance;
        chart.tooltip.options.formatter = function () {
            // UPATE THE TOOLTIP FORMATTER HERE
        };
    }
}
```

Here is a js fiddle example of the issue
http://jsfiddle.net/bteWs/

If you go slowly, and notice the very first point where the switch happens the arrow will be point the wrong direction. After that it corrects ( as described in my post ). Just looking for a solution to get the correct behavior in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always have enabled both classes for tooltip, and just remove inproper in positioner, see: http://jsfiddle.net/bteWs/3/

Default formatter:

```
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<div id="custom-tooltip" class="tooltip-left tooltip-right">';
            var chart = null;
            s += "<div style='padding:5px;color:white'>Some Tooltip</div></div>";
            return s;
        },
```

And removing:

```
            if ((pointX - boxWidth - distance) < plotLeft) {
                x = pointX + 60;
                $("#custom-tooltip").removeClass('tooltip-right');
            }
            else {
                x = Math.max(plotLeft, pointX - boxWidth - 10); 
                $("#custom-tooltip").removeClass('tooltip-left');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is that positioner is begin called after the formatter. I made a fix to your jsfiddle. It's a huge hack but you can see how you can overcome your problem.

In the fix, I made use of a global. You don't need to but I hacked your fiddle in a hurry. I also got rid of some of your duplicate code.

The trick is to force a refresh on the tooltip after the tooltip switch sides.

```
positioner: function (boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {

            // Set up the variables
            var chart = this.chart;
            var plotLeft = chart.plotLeft;
            var plotTop = chart.plotTop;
            var plotWidth = chart.plotWidth;
            var plotHeight = chart.plotHeight;
            var distance = 40;
            var pointX = point.plotX;
            var pointY = point.plotY;
            var refreshTooltip = false;
            var previousAlign = chart.align;

            if ((pointX - boxWidth - distance) < plotLeft) {
                x = pointX + 60;
                chart.align = "left";
            }
            else {
                x = Math.max(plotLeft, pointX - boxWidth - 10); 
                chart.align = "right";

            }
            y = Math.min(plotTop + plotHeight - boxHeight, Math.max(plotTop, pointY - boxHeight + plotTop + boxHeight / 2));

            if (previousAlign != null && chart.align != previousAlign) {
                chart.tooltip.refresh(activePoint);
            }

            return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

See the complete fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/anber500/bteWs/1/